# Use chome "Elements" tab as a HTML editor - save changes

Tags: google-chrome, html

When I run "Inspect element" on some element (HTML is on my local machine) some really easy-to-use Chrome windows appears. I can search and change text strings, but when I want to save my changes anyhow I face some problems.

Does anybody know what should I do to save this HTML locally?

Answer (score 1):

When you make changes through `Inspect element`, it can't save the changes to the actual file. It only saves the changes temporarily on the currently active browser page. When you refresh/re-load the page, the changes will disappear.

You will need a text-editor or an `IDE` (Integrated Development Environment) of some kind in order to make the necessary changes. The Inspect Element option is really only there for experimental purposes. You can experiment with it, but you can't apply the changes as far as I know. If you're making HTML changes, you can just copy the raw html and replace your existing code.